# Flash video broken in 11.2, seeking same location forever

Tags: flash, video, adobe, mp4

I'm trying to get some flash video to play for my users, but as of 11.2 it no longer works. When I do a tcpdump it seems to be seeking the same spot over and over:

```
0x00a0: 001e 5365 656b 696e 6720 3234 3930 3030 ..Seeking.249000
0x00b0: 2028 7374 7265 616d 2049 443a 2031 292e .(stream.ID:.1).
–
0x00a0: 001e 5365 656b 696e 6720 3234 3930 3030 ..Seeking.249000
0x00b0: 2028 7374 7265 616d 2049 443a 2031 292e .(stream.ID:.1).
–
0x00a0: 001e 5365 656b 696e 6720 3234 3930 3030 ..Seeking.249000
0x00b0: 2028 7374 7265 616d 2049 443a 2031 292e .(stream.ID:.1).
```

The videos are in mp4 format and were recorded from streaming video and works fine in versions 11.1 and below. Does anyone know of any video playback related issues in flash player 11.2?

Comment: Is the code that is playing the mp4 video your own, or a 3rd party Flash video player app? In Flash Player 11.2, they significantly changed how video is decoded (now multithreaded). I have seen some Flash Player plugin crashes since 11.2, nothing I can pin down, however.